# ExtensionPoint For Finding Phone Numbers In Native Outlook

Tags: javascript, angular, office365, outlook-addin

I am building an outlook add-in to support detecting phone numbers in emails. I am using the "DetectedEntity" ExtensionPoint. It works fine when using the outlook on web platform (OWA), however the same extension point does not seem to work on the native mac and windows outlook application.

From what I've found in Microsoft's documentation they say "DetectedEntity" will only work for OWA. Anyone know of an ExtensionPoint/Rule or workaround for finding phone numbers in the Native Outlook client(mac/pc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use rules for detecting keywords on the message body:

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
   <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
   <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="myMatch" RegExValue="my_app_name" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
</Rule>
```

Currently only Win Outlook, and OWA support Detected Entity. If a client does not support a certain version override, it should load either older version override sections that it does support, or the legacy section (so you can provide support for older clients that may not support newer features).